# Sitecore web indexing issue for more version items in master database?

Tags: indexing, sitecore, version

When a new version of an item is created in master database, if we edit the item and save and publish it.The item gets published and web database contains the latest updated version item. But while browsing item is not visible on the website
some $name is visible for the item.
Sometimes the item is not visible and sometimes it is visible with $name.
Also when browsing the item directly through url item is visible with latest updated content,so the item is published.Its seems some problem related with indexing.
But when an item is directly edited without the creating a new version,then the issue doesn't exist.So the issue is with the indexing as well as versions as I guess there will be more than one latest versions for the web index which is creating the problem.
How to fix this issue? As a workaround I have to delete the item from web database and republish and rebuild the index again to solve the issue.

Is there a need to customize the existing indexing and crawler strategy for  more than one versions of items?If so which files needs to customize or override and change?"
Here is the code snippet for web indexing for the data items to be displayed?

```
<!-- sitecore_web_content_mag_index -->
        <indexes hint="list:AddIndex">
          <index id="sitecore_web_content_mag_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.SwitchOnRebuildLuceneIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
            <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
            <param desc="folder">$(id)</param>
            <param desc="propertyStore" ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/databasePropertyStore" param1="$(id)" />
            <configuration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration" />
            <strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
              <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/indexUpdateStrategies/onPublishEndAsync" />
            </strategies>
            <commitPolicyExecutor type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.CommitPolicyExecutor, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
              <policies hint="list:AddcommitPolicy">
                <policy type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.TimeIntervalCommitPolicy, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
              </policies>
            </commitPolicyExecutor>
            <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
              <crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
                <Database>web</Database>
                <Root>/sitecore/content/Site/Home</Root>
              </crawler>
            </locations>
          </index>
        </indexes>
```

Comment: How do you retrieve items from web database / index? Do you have multi language site?

Comment: @MarekMusielak i m using  web_content_index strategy to retrieve the items from web. I have multi language site, but the issue is if  i have an item with two versions both in English language in master database. Also, if i remove all old versions of an item in a particular language and then publish it then issue is solved. I have to remove all old versions,which is creating problem if i have to rollback any item content to previous version.

Comment: If you want help, you need to post code which gets data from index and also code which displays data on page.

Comment: @MarekMusielak this is the code which gets data from index...i guess there is no problem with the code which displays data on page because the issue exists for more than one pages which uses this index strategy.Also, the data gets displayed immediately as soon as i save and browse page through master database. Data items which are used for display are buckatable items

Answer (score 0):

When using the ContentSearch API, you can filter the results to return only the latest version by doing something like this:

```
searchContext.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>()
             .Where(result => result["_latestversion"].Equals("1");
```

Or, if you have created your own search result model, you can add a property to it to make the query syntax more consise.

Search Result Model:

```
public class CustomSearchResultItem : SearchResultItem
{
    [IndexField("_latestversion")]
    public bool IsLatestVersion { get; set; }

    // other properties
}
```

Query

```
searchContext.GetQueryable<CustomSearchResultItem>()
             .Where(result => result.IsLatestVersion);
```

Another approach is to use extension methods as described in this post: http://laubplusco.net/generic-extension-methods-sitecore-contentsearch/